# Bloom option in Blender 3.0

Tags: lighting

How to make a Bloom option for a glowing object in Blender 3.0?, in the old versions it is in the render Properties, but in this version I did not find

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be that you have switched to Cycles. This is an EEVEE option and not available in the Cycles.

Comment: Is there an alternative to bloom in a cycles?

Comment: You can use glare node in compositing

Answer (score 0):

### You're probably using Cycles.

To get bloom in Cycles, open the compositor, check *Use Nodes*, and add a *Glare* node between the *Render Layers* node and the *Composite* node.

If you switch to Eevee, there's a *Bloom* checkbox in the Render Settings.

(To switch between Eevee and Cycles, use the dropdown at the top of the Render Settings.)